# Access column from another model with where rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have the following relationships in my application, one event belongs to venue, and one venue belongs to a region. So, now in my action `show` in the `events_controller.rb file`, I want to show the related events which have the same category and region with the current event. However, the thing is there is no region_id in my events table. I tried to use where like this `@events = Event.check_event_validation.where(["category_id = ? and id != ? and venue.region = ?", @event.category_id, @event.id, @event.venue.region])`
And it shows me this error:

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "venue"
>   LINE 1: ...10.772518') AND (category_id = 5 and id != 10 and
>   venue.regi... ^ : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "events" WHERE (starts_at >
>   '2016-03-28 13:52:10.772518') AND (category_id = 5 and id != 10 and
>   venue.region = 1)

It works if I change the above code to this: `@events = Event.check_event_validation.where(["category_id = ? and id != ?", @event.category_id, @event.id])`
However, this is not I want because it will leave out all the events that are in the same region with the current event. So, could anybody give me a suggestion or a guide into the right direction? I know that I can apply the same logic in my view and it will work fine, but I want to apply the logic in my controller not the view.

Here are my files:

**events_controller.rb**:

```
 def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @events = Event.check_event_validation.where(["category_id = ? and id != ? and venue.region = ?", @event.category_id, @event.id, @event.venue.region])
end
```

**event.rb**:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :venue
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :ticket_types
end
```

**schema.rb**:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160327074316) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "starts_at"
    t.datetime "ends_at"
    t.integer  "venue_id"
    t.string   "hero_image_url"
    t.text     "extended_html_description"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "events", ["category_id"], name: "index_events_on_category_id", using: :btree
  add_index "events", ["venue_id"], name: "index_events_on_venue_id", using: :btree

  create_table "regions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "ticket_types", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "event_id"
    t.integer  "price"
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "max_quantity"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "ticket_id"
  end

  add_index "ticket_types", ["event_id"], name: "index_ticket_types_on_event_id", using: :btree

  create_table "tickets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.integer  "ticket_type"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "username"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["username"], name: "index_users_on_username", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "venues", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "full_address"
    t.integer  "region_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  add_index "venues", ["region_id"], name: "index_venues_on_region_id", using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "events", "categories"
  add_foreign_key "events", "venues"
  add_foreign_key "ticket_types", "events"
  add_foreign_key "venues", "regions"
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd like to join the venues table,

```
@events_in_the_same_region = Event.joins(:venue).where(
  events: { category: @event.category },
  venues: { region_id: @event.venue.region.id }
)
```

This would return all the events which are within the same category and their venues are at the same region as the specific `@event`

Comment: Thank you so much. Although I gotta edit your code to this:
`@events_in_the_same_region = Event.joins(:venue).where(
      events: { category_id: @event.category_id },
      venues: { region_id: @event.venue.region }
    )`

Otherwise, it will throw me the error:

`PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column venues.region does not exist  LINE 1: ...ues" ON "venues"."id" = "events"."venue_id" WHERE 
"venues"."... ^ : SELECT "events".* FROM "events" INNER JOIN 
 "venues" ON "venues"."id" = "events"."venue_id" WHERE 
 "venues"."region" = 2 AND "events"."category" = 6`

Comment: Just one more question, now everything works fine. However, I don't want to show the user the current event again in the related events group. Therefore, how can I add that condition in the join table, for example `where(id != @event.id)`.